# Amazon S3 Expiration Date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I hope this question isn't too rudimentary, but I'm confused...

In the S3 documentation I read:

> All HTTP queries have an expiration
>   parameter that allows you to set how
>   long the query will be valid. For
>   example, you can configure a web page
>   graphic to expire after a very long
>   period of time or a software download
>   to only last for 24 hours.

For a publicly accessible data object (file), does this mean that the data object (file) itself will not be valid anymore, or that the browser will simply re-cache the object after the expiration date.  As in, will I lose my data after ten years if I set my expirations that long?  Or if I set a download for 24 hours, is it gone/inaccessible past that?

What if I don't set an expiration date?

Answer (score 44):

I believe you are referring to the signed urls for private data stored on Amazon S3.

If files are publicly accessible they can be accessed with a simple url to the file:

eg `http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[key]`

However, they can be set to [private](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingAuthAccess.html) in which case you need to provide a [signed url](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?S3_QSAuth.html) to access the file. This url is created using your public and secret keys, and its this url that has an expiry time. eg

```
http://[bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/[key]?AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS_Public_Key]&Expires=1294766482&Signature=[generated_hash]
```

As per your question, for web graphics, you might re-use the same generated url with the expiry time set far into the future so that browsers can cache the file, whereas for file downloads you'd probably create a new url for each request with the url set to expire only a day in advance to protect your data.

This **DOES NOT**  expire/delete/remove your data stored on S3. It only affects the url to the file and you can generate as many urls with different expiry dates as you require.

Comment: You can also invalidate all URLs pointing to an object on S3 by renaming or moving or deleting the object. That's pretty obvious once you understand that the URLs you make are just that - they point to a file on your S3 account, and amazon does not even know when you make one - you don't need an internet connection to make a signed URL.