# Is it possible to share files for selective users using Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have few files in my S3 bucket. Is it possible to share them with selected users. Those people might not have Amazon S3 account. I know if i make it public everyone could able to download the files using URL.

I want something like an encrypted URL or an URL that asks for some Username and password immediately when it is been hit.

And also i do not want to install any new/ third party softwares to be installed by everyone.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely.

You can make your files [private](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingAuthAccess.html) and then generate [time expiring signed urls](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?S3_QSAuth.html) to your files.

The signed urls are generated using your public key and secret key and are set to expire at a specified time in the future.

Depending on what technology you are using, its probably easiest to generate the urls using one of the [AWS SDKS](http://aws.amazon.com/code?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1).

Signed urls look something like:

```
http://[bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/[key]?AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS_Public_Key]&Expires=1294766482&Signature=[generated_hash]
```

I explain a bit more about these urls in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643328/amazon-s3-expiration-date/4649553#4649553).

Comment: question.  is there a vulnerability of accidentally granting access to other files in the same s3 folder?

Comment: @arcee123 - signed urls (ie the signature) is only valid for the file you create it for. It can't be used for any other files. So the only risk is user error - ie you accidentally sign the wrong file and give that to the user.

Comment: brilliant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample ruby code to generate signed urls for a particular location in your bucket.

Install `aws-sdk`:

```
gem install aws-sdk
```

Create a new file, name it as you want, I choose `shareS3files.rb` see it on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/onrails/75b05a71ca3f18d3d786):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'aws-sdk'
require 'json'

#loading credentials
creds = JSON.load(File.read('secrets.json'))
creds = Aws::Credentials.new(creds['AccessKeyId'], creds['SecretAccessKey'])

#loading config
conf = JSON.load(File.read('config.json'))

# Create a new S3 object
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(credentials: creds, region: conf['Region'])

# Create a resource object, simpler to use
resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: s3)
bucket = resource.bucket(conf['Bucket'])

# enumerate every object in a bucket, and create a pre signed url with a 5 days expiration limit
bucket.objects(prefix: 'conf['Location']').each do |obj|
  puts "#{obj.key} => #{obj.object.presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 5 * 24 * 60 * 60)}"
end
```

Now, create both credential and configuration files:

`secrets.json`:

```
{
  "AccessKeyId": "TOCHANGE",
  "SecretAccessKey": "TOCHANGE"
}
```

`config.json`:

```
{
  "Region": "TOCHANGE",
  "Bucket": "tochange",
  "Location": "to/change/"
}
```

Further aws and ruby doc:

- [Kit SDK AWS pour Ruby](http://aws.amazon.com/fr/sdk-for-ruby/)
- [AWS SDK for Ruby V2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/#Installation)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/) installed you can simply use [presign](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html).

```sh
aws s3 presign s3://[bucket]/[path_filename]
```

You can also set the link to expire in 24hrs `86400 = (60 * 60 * 24))`

```sh
aws s3 presign s3://[bucket]/[path_filename] --expires-in 86400
```