# Resuming expiring S3 links with iOS background downloading (NSURLSession)

Tags: ios7, amazon-s3

Consider the following components of a media download system:

- There is a server component that generates private, expiring links to S3 Objects with rather *short lifetimes* (see e.g. [Amazon S3 pre-signed link generation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) or [Amazon S3 Expiration Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643328/amazon-s3-expiration-date)) - basically for security reasons. In S3, the expiry date is part of the link signature and thus part of the generated URL
- An app can request such a link for downloading potentially large media content
- Should such a link expire, the app can re-request the content, receiving a *new* link (because of the new signature) pointing to the *same* S3 Object

This setup should allow for resuming downloads beyond the lifetime of a download link (by simply stitching together content downloaded from various links).

With iOS 7, we now have the iOS background transfer service and [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html). Sadly, it seems that when you give a link to a `NSURLSession` and this link expires and the download thus fails, the content downloaded so far is lost.

So, is there any way to **resume a download** in the above scenario using the **background transfer service**?

How do you *resume* downloading the same content from a second source? Or can you provide a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` with fail-over handling when a download attempt fails? Or alternatively, is there any chance to get the downloaded content "so far" in order to do the stitching yourself?

Alternatively, are there any strategies on the server side to solve this (and no, I don't want to put my own Web server before the link to channel all S3 traffic through)?

Comment: How did you end up addressing this, @CoSeeWolf? I'm running into the same issue. I've read some things that suggest a good approach might be to set a high expiry time and use the aws:Referer condition key in the bucket policy to restrict access.

Answer (score 0):

The only idea I can think of, is to create a timer based on link expiration time

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? A timer on which side (server / client)? Causing what?

Comment: What you could do, is to create a timer on client side. When the time expires (or even before that), you pause the download, get the new link and restart the download.

Comment: This would not work with NSURLSessionDownloadTask / background transfer service as stated in the question. As of my knowledge you can't change the URL of a paused download or when resuming it.

Comment: We are also using Amazon S3 expiring links and changing the URL of a paused download actually works :)

Comment: With NSURLSessionDownloadTask? This is the key point here! With NSURLSessionDataTask / NSURLConnection this works, but then background download beyond 10 minutes is not available.

Comment: Yep! We are using NSURLSessionDownloadTask, it works in background.

Comment: Ah, you talked about "restarting the download", so you don't resume the previous partial download? Just cancel the old expired one? We're trying to enable resuming previous expired downloads with new URLs.

Comment: When the time expires (or even before that), you have to:
1. pause the download - NSURLConnection will give you through didFailWithError method the data you have already downloaded
2. retrieve the new link
3. restart the download with the new URL and the data you have.

Comment: Now your talking about NSURLConnection. This is not related to NSURLSessionDownloadTask at all! With NSURLConnection this is easy, but also has no background downloading functionality. What is it now that you really use in your system?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong. NSURLSessionTaskDelegate throws didFailWithError